# Можно ли взять массив строк и в одной из строки выбрать один элемент?

Tags: c++, строки

Есть некий массив строк:
`string mass[n] = {"Евгений","Дмитрий","Василий"}`

И мне нужно каким-то способом взять ну например букву "м" из "Дмитрия".

Я пытался таким способом, но он не работает: `mass[1].substr[1, 1];`

Как ещё это можно сделать?

Помогите разобраться, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что значит "не канает"?

```
std::string names[] = { "Test","ABC","Doom" };
std::cout << names[1].substr(1, 1) << std::endl;
```

выводит `B` как и положено

и

```
std::string names[] = { "Test","ABC","Doom" };
std::cout << names[1][1] << std::endl;
```

выводит `B` как и положено

Так что канает

Если же у вас проблемы с русским - добавьте в начале кода (сразу после `int main() {`)

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

тогда и с русским текстом начнет канать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]